# Segmentation of Geodemographic Data

Tags: clustering, spatial

I have a dataset that has 5 variables (columns). These are median house price, median income, number of people with no educational degree, number of people with high school degree, number of people with university degree. I have these variables by different census sub-divisions. So rows represent different census sub-divisions. I am interested to segment this data into smaller number of segments e.g. (Low, Average, High) income, (Low, Average, High) house, (Highly or Less) educated.

In other words, I want to e.g. find a way to define ranges for (Low, Average, High) income levels in following two cases:

1. By considering the geographical location i.e. census sub-divisions
2. Without considering the geographical location i.e. census sub-divisions.

At first I thought that maybe k-means clustering is appropriate (at least for the 2nd case above where I am not considering the census sub-divisions). But this does not seem right to me as I am having both prices/incomes and number of people in the dataset. Also this approach gives me centers of each cluster and not actually the ranges for each levels: Low, Average, and High.

Is there any other approach I can use?

Comment: Would it be fair to say that you are interested in a *supervised* learning algorithm where income is the target and the other features are predictors of income? Next, you want to do it two ways: 1) based on a model that includes geography in @anony-mousse's sense (below) in terms of proximity or nearest neighbor and, 2) a model that ignores geography, correct?

Comment: Not exactly, I don't have any response variable here. So the answer to your 1st question is no. I am interested in two cases: with and without considering the geographic correlation among variables.

Comment: Ok...but how do you propose integrating geography in a "correlation?"

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of approaches.

Instead of relying on k-means that is sensitive to outliers, why don't you just consider values below the 1QR to be low (i.e. the botrom 25%) and values larger than the 3QR (i.e. the top 25%) to be high?
IQRs are rather robust statistics.
You cold also use low=below $\mu-\sigma$ and high=above $\mu+\sigma$ where $\mu$ is the mean and $\sigma$ is the standard deviation. But this won't work well on skewed data (and income probably is skewed).

For geography, you can do this with respect to the neighbors only.

Comment: I have already thought of this approach. But this ignores the correlations among variables which is not good I guess.

Comment: So does k-means. It optimizes the sum of variances, but it does not pay any spwcial attention to correlation. And if you want low/med/high in ever attribute, you would need to cluster them separately.

Comment: Maybe I didnt use the term "correlation" properly here. What I meant is that e.g. in the k-means we are finding the distances in a multivariate sense. So geographical coordinates in combination of income, education, etc.

Comment: k-means only works with squared Euclidean, not on geographic distance like haversine and won't produce "levels".